# Azure Mobile Services .Net Backend

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

The sample service project you can download from Azure implements a web api controller that inherits from TableController.  This works as expected with no issues.  However, I prefer to use the standard Azure Custom Web Controller (avail from Add->New->Custom Azure API Controller).  This controller uses EF6 but does not inherit from TableController and for some reason will not allow you to save the sample Todoitem without providing the key (guid) upfront.  Again, the Tablecontroller based API does not require this.

This is the standard API Custom API  (does not work unless I provide the Id value)

```
td.Text = "hello there";
td.Complete = false;
ctx.TodoItems.Add(td);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

This is the TableController derived API controller..this works, no id required

```
DataObjects.TodoItem td = new TodoItem();
td.Text = "hello there";
td.Complete = false;
TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(td);
return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
```

I am thinking that the TableController class is a must but I am not sure why

**UPDATE- the Id field has (newid()) as its default value.**

**UPDATE - I think I found the answer:
            modelBuilder.Entity().Property(m => m.Id)
             .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);**

Thanks
Bob